# is javascript's `return` really a *keyword*?

Tags: javascript, language-design

this snip will ran without any complain on both nodejs and the browser:

```
this.return = function ( x ) { 
    return x 
};

console.log ( this.return(1) );
```

I was expecting it to fail hard with a syntax error.

I meant, I can understand why `this['return']` works.. but I always though `return` was a lexer keyword?

is javascript a context-sensitive language?

**added**: the point is that the lexer does not have a T_RETURN token, but it uses some T_STRING instead. Isn't?

Comment: You can overwrite undefined too. Doesn't mean it's a good idea! Edit: technically you're not overwriting return.

Comment: I know nothing about interpreters, but to me it just "makes sense" that after such a `.`, anything that can be parsed as an identifier is valid.

Comment: It is a reserved keyword, but those can be used as properties without an error popping up, it's just a very bad idea to do so.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zr4u1zfn/

Comment: @Niet: Knowing a bit about parsing myself, it surprises me the opposite way -- normally, lexing (turning the raw text into a stream of tokens at the pure syntax level) is the very first step, and that would tag keywords regardless of usage context.

Comment: This surprised me because I seem to remember having had a problem before where I used `do` as a property name, forgetting that it was a keyword.  But I think that may have been in an object literal, so I guess it's different.  I also recall it affecting different browsers differently.

Comment: @JosiahKeller: The difference is in the changes from ECMAScript 3 to ECMAScript 5. Object literals in ES5 can use keyword property identifiers without issue.

Answer (score 10):

`return` is a [**reserved keyword**](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words.html), but reserved keywords can be used as a [**property accessors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) without issue, it's just generally bad practice to do so.

Reserved keywords may specifically not be used as names for variables, functions, methods, or identifiers for arrays and objects, because ECMAScript specifies special behavior for them:

The source text from ECMAScript scripts gets scanned from left to right and is converted into a sequence of input elements which are tokens, control characters, line terminators, comments or white space.

ECMAScript also defines certain keywords and literals and has rules for automatic insertion of semicolons to end statements.

Reserved words actually only apply to Identifiers (vs. IdentifierNames).
As described in [**ES5**](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6), these are all IdentifierNames which do not exclude ReservedWords.

```
a.return
a["return"]
a = { return: "test" }.
```

However these are not

```
function return() {}
var return;
```

[More on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar)

Comment: I came across something similar before. While technically possible, it is considered a bad idea to use reserved keywords because it makes your code difficult to read and understand later.

Comment: @kittycat3141: I'd say it's bad practice because a) people may not be used to it (which might be what you are referring to) and b) the code doesn't run in older versions of IE8. However, a) will hopefully change once ES6 is released (which defines `Map#delete`).

Comment: @FelixKling - and it's easy to get confused, one minute you're doing `foo["return"]`, the next you're doing `foo[return]` and can't understand why it won't work. Also some minification software and/or IDE's can have issues when suddenly seeing `return` where it doesn't belong, especially if you do things like `foo.return`

Comment: How's that different than one minute doing `foo["bar"]` and the next minute doing `foo[bar]`? With the keyword it can be easier to fix the problem because of the syntax error, whereas if you have a `bar` variable defined, the issue is far less clear. IDEs and minifiers that don't understand ES5 need to be updated or left behind.

Comment: @sixfingeredman - It's not really, but you'd have to define `return` somewhere to do `foo[return]` and it could be confusing to people who don't really know the reserved keywords, that's all. There's questions on here all the time where people start using `this` or `delete` in the strangest ways, the point was merely that it's generally better to stay away from the reserved keywords, even if they are fully allowed as properties.

Comment: i think {"return":123} would be ok in IE8, but {return:123} would not. it's not the reservation, it's the application.

Comment: @adeneo: I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, return is a keyword. You have defined a property and essentially used a string named return. Had you actually used return it would have caused an error

```js
var return = "error";//Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return
```

Comment: You are taking about "define", which happens really really later in the process.. Lexer -> Scanner -> Parser. I was expecting it to raise an error at scanner-level.